# How to implement SQL Row_number in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to number my dataframe records using SQL "Row_number over" function available in SQL but it results in error as shown in the image. Please note that I don't wish to number records using Pandas function.

Here is the code

```
df1.head()
```

output of df1.head statement

```
date    beef    veal    pork    lamb_and_mutton broilers    other_chicken   turkey
0   1944-01-01 00:00:00.000000  751.0   85.0    1280.0  89.0    NaN NaN NaN
1   1944-02-01 00:00:00.000000  713.0   77.0    1169.0  72.0    NaN NaN NaN
2   1944-03-01 00:00:00.000000  741.0   90.0    1128.0  75.0    NaN NaN NaN
3   1944-04-01 00:00:00.000000  650.0   89.0    978.0   66.0    NaN NaN NaN
4   1944-05-01 00:00:00.000000  681.0   106.0   1029.0  78.0    NaN NaN NaN
```

---

```
p = """SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date ASC) AS Row#,
  beef,veal
FROM df1"""

df1 = pysqldf(p)
```

Once I execute this statement it throws an error

This code is from Python 3 version. Normal SQL queries work but looks like this row_number function isn't available/supported by Python. Can you please help me with this? I receive an operational error

Comment: Hi SELVA, welcome to SO. Please read something about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and eventually share with us `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Please be considerate of the fact that not all pandas experts are aware of SQL functions or what Row_Number does. Just state your expected output, that's more easily understandable/relatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple and you might have figured it out already. The # breaks the whole thing as that is an unrecognized token.

If you leave that out, your code should work.

```
from pandasql import sqldf

q1='select beef, veal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) as RN FROM df1'

df_new=sqldf(q1)
```

Also it is a good practice to name your headers differently from the basic syntax. Date and row can be a functions in SQL, so you better go with 'RN' for the row column and 'date_' or 'date_of_purchase' for the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same functionality in pandas by using the two lines of code:

1. Sort the dataframe by date

   ```
   >>>df1.sort_values(by='date')
   ```
2. Add an additional column named "Row#"

   ```
   >>>df1["Row#"]=range(1,len(df1["date"])+1)
   ```